# Pass array into array of arrays by value, not reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-value

I have an array of coordinates (`coods`), which are therefore smaller arrays, which I want to add new arrays to. I want it to look like this:

```
[
[0,2],
[0,1],
[0,0]
]
```

I want to do this by adding a constantly changing variable `new` to it every time the code runs:

```
coods.unshift(new);
```

The only problem is that (as took me forever to discover), when passing a new array into the larger array it is only passing a reference, not the value itself, so I end up having a `coods` array of:

```
[
[0,2],
[0,2],
[0,2]
]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, yes, objects and arrays are always handled "by reference". If you want to make a copy of it, you need to explicitly make a copy. Is your question how to create a copy of an array? Without more concrete code on how these arrays are created we can't help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `coods.unshift(new.slice())` to add a copy of the array.  (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Alternatively there is probably a way of changing the design of the code so that this isn't a problem, but if not then `slice` is probably the way to go.  You may want to use a specific cloning function (several libraries have them, or write your own that uses slice) to make it more semantic though.